# iOS - UIScreen setBrightness doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiscreen

Simply doing this:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.2];
```

Doesn't work. Has no effect at all on the app. Is there some other setting I need to set for this to work?

Comment: on which ios you are working on?

Answer (score 2):

It does work on the device, but not on the simulator.

Comment: Yes. I was testing on the simulator originally.

Comment: not working after set [device setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES] and [UIDevice currentDevice].proximityState is active,you can't set screen setBrightness,